# How to add swipe gesture on a fullscreen mode MPMoviePlayerController in IOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller, fullscreen, gesture

I tried to add a swipe gesture to `player.view.subviews[0].`

I googled for many times but could not get a working solution.

My code is very normal. just like

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeAction:)];
UIView *subView = player.view.subviews[0];
[subView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
```

It works in IOS5 but not in 6 when player is in fullscreen mode.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Mpmovieplaertsontroller enters full-screen mode, it creates an additional window (usually the last in the list of application windows). From this we can test all possible views and subviews and find the necessary controls. Then you can put everything you need. 
For example, how to add swipes to the MPMoviePlayer.

```
- (void)didEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification*)notification {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 target:self selector:@selector(showFullScreenControls) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)showFullScreenControls {
    NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
    UIWindow* mpfullscreenwindow = [windows lastObject];
    gestureView = mpfullscreenwindow.subviews[0];
    testbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [testbutton setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    testbutton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 50, 100, 50);
    testbutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [testbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(alertBtnAction) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [mpfullscreenwindow addSubview:testbutton];
    [gestureView addGestureRecognizer:_leftSwipeRecognizer];
    [gestureView addGestureRecognizer:_rightSwipeRecognizer];
}
```

Comment: It works in IOS7. Thanks a lot!
BTW: It still does not work in IOS6.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding the gesture recognizers to one of the player's views, you could add the recognizers to your own view (the one that contains the player view). Just be sure to clear `cancelsTouchesInView` to give the underlying views a crack at the touches.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeAction:)];
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
swipeLeft.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
```

I've successfully used this approach in the same situation.

Comment: I tried this way but still have no luck. Anyway, thanks for your help. BTW: My ios version is 6.1.3

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add a gesture recognizer to the window when the player goes to full screen mode (first catching that notification event).

```
func moviePlayerDidEnterFullscreen (notification : NSNotification) {
    self.window?.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUpGestureRecognizer)
}
```